# 'CGContextAddLineToPoint' is unavailable : Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

What is replace of the `CGContextAddLineToPoint` this is what I'm trying to do

```
 for i in aerr {
     //0.5f offset lines up line with pixel boundary
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, self.font!.lineHeight * CGFloat(x) + baselineOffset)
                
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGFloat(self.bounds.size.width), self.font!.lineHeight * CGFloat(x) + baselineOffset)
 }
```

and I'm getting the following error. I know they clearly mention using `move(to:)` but how to use that?

> 'CGContextMoveToPoint' is unavailable: Use move(to:) instead

Comment: `move(to:)` is a method on `CGContext`, so it'd be `context.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.origin.x, y: self.font!.lineHeight * CGFloat(x) + baselineOffset)` Same logic for `CGContextAddLineToPoint` with `context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(self.bounds.size.width), y:self.font!.lineHeight * CGFloat(x) + baselineOffset)`

Comment: Use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer

Comment: In addition to the observations below, about `context.move` and `context.addLine`, another alternative is to just create a `UIBezierPath`, use `path.move` and `path.addLine`, and then `path.stroke()` (or `fill()`, as needed). I’ve retired all my `CGContext` related path drawing. It’s only in very narrow cases where you need to drop to `CGContext` functions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, you can simply use directly from your `context` because it methods is part of [CGContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext).

So `CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y)` will be `context.move(to:CGPoint(x, y))`

As same as, `CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y)` will be `context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x, y))`

So your code will be

```swift
guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

for i in aerr {
     //0.5f offset lines up line with pixel boundary
    context.move(to: CGPoint(x:  self.bounds.origin.x, y: self.font!.lineHeight * CGFloat(x) + baselineOffset))
    
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(self.bounds.size.width), y: self.font!.lineHeight * CGFloat(x) + baselineOffset))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
context.move(to: .init(x: self.bounds.origin.x, y: self.font!.lineHeight * CGFloat(x) + baselineOffset))
```